# Is there a way to divide and map a date into months with their sum of daily value?

Tags: java, date, mapping

Im having trouble thinking of a way to create a function that can calculate the monthly spends of all combined projects in a system and return a map with month as its key and the monthly spends as their value. By monthly spends I mean the worked hours of the employees multiplied by their wage.

The class Project has a startdate and an end date with a function that calculates the working days in between. Each project has differen start and end date.

```
public int getNumWorkingDays() {
    return utils.Calendar.getNumWorkingDays(this.startDate, this.endDate);
}
```

the project also has an committedHoursPerDay() function that maps the employee to the amount of worked hours per day.

```
private Map<Employee,Integer> committedHoursPerDay;
```

How can i create a function that can sum up the spendings based on each month keeping the start and end date in mind for each individual project?

```
Map<Month,Integer> monthlyBudget;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is very broad for a Stack Overflow question. Sum up the hours per day for all employees on the project. Use `YearMonth` (from java.time) for the months of the duration of the project. Iterate over those months. For each month get the first and the last day (there are methods for that) and pass them to your utility for finding number of working days. Multiply by the total number of hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course I'll not do your programming job for you, but I can give you some things to consider.

## `YearMonth`

To represent a month, use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY ) ;
```

You can get the `YearMonth` for any date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.MARCH , 27 ) ;
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.from( ld ) ;
```

That class can be used as the key of your map. As for the value part of a map's [key-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute%E2%80%93value_pair) pairing, if you are talking about currency amounts that are fractional, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for [accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems), never the [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) types, float or double.

```
Map< YearMonth , BigDecimal > monthlyTotals = new TreeMap<> () ;
```

## `Map` implementations

As for which [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) implementation to choose, you may want one that keeps the keys in chronological order of those `YearMonth` objects. If so, choose one that implements [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html). Two such implementations are bundled with Java 11: `TreeSet` and [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html). Use the second if manipulating your map across threads.

Here is a table I made summarizing the features of the various map implementations bundled with Java 11.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

## Elapsed days

> The class Project has a startdate and an end date with a function that calculates the working days in between

Use [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) class to count elapsed days. Uses the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.FEBRUARY , 15 ) ;
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

If you want to omit certain days of the week to count only "working days", then [search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20working%20days&t=ffab&atb=v197-1&ia=web) to learn more as that has been covered many times. You likely will want to look at the temporal adjusters in the *ThreeTen-Extra* library.